# Add a filter to appender in elasticsearch - logging yml syntax

Tags: syntax, filter, elasticsearch, log4j

I am using Elasticsearch v1.3.2.

I would like to switch on logging of slow search executions times, but I would like to filter out searches against marvel.

Elasticsearch seems to say we can customise the logging based on the log4j v1.2 documentation (see bottom of w ww.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html)

I've had a look at the log4j v1.2 doc (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html, and http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat?highlight=%28filter%29), and it looks as though I should be able to add a stringMatchFilter to the index_search_slow_log_file appender, but everything I try spits it out.

This is what I expect should work in logging.yml:

```
index_search_slow_log_file:
  type: dailyRollingFile
  file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_search_slowlog.log
  datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
  layout:
    type: pattern
    conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
  filter: 
      type: stringMatchFilter
        acceptOnMatch: true
        stringToMatch: "marvel"
```

This gives this exception:

```
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [filter] to value "stringMatchFilter".
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [true].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: true
     at ..........
```

I've also tried:

```
index_search_slow_log_file:
  ...
  filter: 
      type: stringMatch
        acceptOnMatch: true
        stringToMatch: "marvel"
```

and every other combination I can think of, including removing quotation marks.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Isabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit incomplete :-), please use the following and see if it works for you. Filters syntax uses an identifier, thus the `1` in my configuration below. Also, note that if you want to filter out the "marvel" ones then you need `acceptOnMatch: false`.

```
filter:
  1:
    type: org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
    StringToMatch: "marvel"
    AcceptOnMatch: false
```

Comment: Thank you!  Tried it and it works great.  Cool, yeah I did try adding an identifier too, but using the full class name was what I had missed.  Ah oops, I must have switched the 'false' to 'true' during debugging too eheh.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that the level that you log to index_search_slow_log_file can be specific to the index.

So I don't actually need to filter out marvel logs, I can just set the default to no logging in elasticsearch.yml (i.e. don't change it), enable logging to index_search_slow_log_file and then put an index specific override via the index settings API.

**elasticsearch.yml:** no change

**logging.yml:**

```
additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: true
  ...
```

**Index settings API:**

```
PUT /index_name/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "search": {
      "slowlog": {
        "threshold": {
          "fetch": {
            "trace": "0ms",
            "info": "500ms",
            "warn": "1s"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [andrei-stefan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan) answer, you can also invert the sense of matching to `AcceptOnMatch: true`, but this requires adding an explicit `DenyAllFilter` after.  The full example looks like this:

```
filter:
  1:
    type: org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
    StringToMatch: "my-important-index"
    AcceptOnMatch: true
  2:
    type: org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```